# Why is rspec not seeing these class methods?

Tags: ruby, rspec

If I have ruby file `maze.rb` with

```
class Maze
  def self.x
  end 
  def self.y
  end 
end
```

and a rspec file with

```
require 'maze'

describe "A Maze" do
  it "exists" do
    expect(Maze).to be
  end 
  it " has x-y dimension" do
    expect(Maze.x).to be
    expect(Maze.y).to be
  end 
end
```

Why does the test for Maze.x fail ?

Failures:

```
1) A Maze  has x-y dimension
   Failure/Error: expect(Maze.x).to be
     expected nil to evaluate to true
   # ./spec/maze_spec.rb:8:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working.

What's happening is that the class level method isn't doing anything and thus returns nil - as opposed to `method not found`.  Simply adding `true` as the return value resolves this, i.e.

```
def x
  true
end
```